show text link side-by-side with the figure
I want to show the link text (e.g., googlescholar/user.com) as a hyperlink, side-by-side with an icon (figure). I used the below method, but it only show a figure or a text. Can i amend this approach to include both, or if there is a better method ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\href{http://www.googlescholar.com}{\includegraphics[width=5cm] 
{googlescholar}}
\end{document}

A solution suggested by @John Kormylo gives this results. I need the text to be at the right side of the icon.


\href{http://www.googlescholar.com}{http://www.googlescholar.com \includegraphics[width=5cm]  {example-image}} ?

See also \url{...}  Currently you are making the image the (clickable) link.

@JohnKormylo, thank you. The issue is, the text appears before the icon, i need the text to the right of the icon. I attached a snipshot of it up

I wasn't sure what you were trying to achieve.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\advance\parskip by \baselineskip

\href{http://www.googlescholar.com}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip, valign=t] 
{example-image}} \url{http://www.googlescholar.com}% two separate links

\href{http://www.googlescholar.com}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip, valign=t] 
{example-image} \nolinkurl{http://www.googlescholar.com}}% single link

\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip, valign=t]{example-image} \url{http://www.googlescholar.com}% icon not linked

\href{http://www.googlescholar.com}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip, valign=t] 
{example-image}} \nolinkurl{http://www.googlescholar.com}% url not linked
\end{document}


Great answer, thank you.
